# How to get a list of tuples from a Django RawQuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm doing a complex query with raw SQL within django to solve some annotation issues.
The actual query has many left joins that have been converted to subqueries in order to get around a major bug in Django.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060

Given

```
fields = ['shift__adminFee',                                      
        'shift__rosterSlot__adminFee',
        'shift__taxi__rosterGroup__adminFee',
        'shift__driver__adminFee']

query = `''select table.id, "table_shift"."adminFee"
, "table_rosterslot"."adminFee"
, "table_rostergroup"."adminFee"
, "table_driver"."adminFee"  from table 
left join ( select table_id, sum(amount) amount_sum from related_table group by table_id ) related_table
on table.id = related_table.table_id
...
( more inner joins and tables to support the above fields )
'''
rawQuerySet = Table.objects.raw(q)
```

which returns a RawQuerySet.

The RawQuerySet works well ... and it populates the related models as well as giving the correct annotated results.

The RawQuerySet however doesn't support returning a list of tuples.

I've looked through the source file which locally in the project is 'env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py'
but I don't understand it yet and I had a result to produce.

So instead of doing  results_as_list_of_tuples = query.values_list(*fields)
I did something like

```
    results_as_list_of_tuples = []
    for result in query:
        shift = result.shift
        eventSchedule = shift.eventSchedule
        rosterSlot = shift.rosterSlot
        taxi = shift.taxi
        rosterGroup = taxi.rosterGroup

        data = []
        ...
        # the following is one line. I broke it up because it didn't format correctly.
        data.extend([
            shift.adminFee
            ,rosterSlot.adminFee
            ,rosterGroup.adminFee
            ,driver.adminFee]
        )
        ...
        results_as_list_of_tuples.append(tuple(data))
```

How to get a list of tuples from a Django RawQuerySet with 
something like results_as_list_of_tuples = values_list(raw_query_set,*fields)

Comment: I have similar requirement to get list of tuples/dictionary when using `objects.raw`. Did you happen to find a clean solution?

Comment: I used the pattern in the answer by hynekcer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of column names from **`RawQuerySet`** by **`columns`** property. A **`values_list`** iterator can be created from a raw queryset this way:

```
def raw_queryset_as_values_list(raw_qs):
    columns = raw_qs.columns
    for row in raw_qs:
        yield tuple(getattr(row, col) for col in columns)
```

The property `columns` is undocumented, but steady.

Comment: great solution, thanks. If anyone wants to use this output in Pandas Dataframe, use

      "p = pandas.DataFrame(raw_queryset_as_values_list(cc), columns=list(cc.columns))" 
, where cc is RawQuerySet